# casting to top level interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

given

`IObject<T>`
and
`IResult<T>`

```
public interface IObjectHandler<TQ, TR> where TQ : IObject<TR>

Task<IResult<TR>> DoIt(TQ o);
```

I create an instances of intefaces
`TestObject : IObject<bool>`

`TestResult<T> : IResult<T>`

`TestObjectHandler : IObjectHandler<TestObject, bool>`

when TestObjectHandler DoIt method is called it should return a TestResult object with type bool.

There will be a one to one on the IObject to IObjectHandler implementations.
There will be many different IObject and handler classes.
At the point of execution we only know about the IObject.  We want to register all the implementations with the IServiceCollection, then use the IServiceProvider to get the correct handler when required.

something like (where obj is an IObject)

```
var handlerType = typeof(IObjectHandler<,>);
var constructedHandler = handlerType.MakeGenericType(obj.GetType(), typeof(T));
var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(handlerType);
```

If I manually cast to IObjectHandler<TestObject, bool> then I can call DoIt.

but if I try to cast to (where T would be bool)
`IObjectHandler<IObject<T>, T>`

the cast will fail.

I am looking for a way to be able to call DoIt and get the correct casted object back.

I do not want to use reflection as they would be slower than needed.
I could create a non generic interface to be able to call that, but either I then have to have a base class that implements the non generic and casts the objects for me, or leave two methods where there should only be one.

This project could be consumed by various different people, so insisting they have to use the base class rather than just go off the interface or have two uglier methods is less than  ideal.

I get the feeling the base class is the best way forward. hoping someone might have a better idea

Comment: You appear to be trying to implement the mediator pattern, have you tried `mediatr`?

Comment: @neil thx.  that was the pointer I needed. took a few nuggets from Mediatr to finish it off

Answer (score 0):

@neil gave me a pointer to the answer.  It was a Mediator pattern I was trying to implement.

what I needed was an intermediate layer. take the IObject type and return type, use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of a generic class that has all the generic parameters required.  then can use IServiceProvider to get the correct handler with a typed parameter.

see https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/src/MediatR/Wrappers/RequestHandlerWrapper.cs